# Cannot read property id of undefined, error found in the map function (react-rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, dictionary

I'm trying to make my submit button add on to the list of items, my seed data in rails gets rendered fine but when I try to add a new item when clicking submit, I get this error `Cannot read property id of undefined` which is found at the map function. The post request works fine, and only after I refresh the page, the item I add gets rendered on the page. Any help would be appreciated!

```
class TodoList extends React.Component {


render() {
    const {todos} = this.props
    var todoItems = todos.map(title => <TodoItem key={title.id} title={title}/>)           //here
    return (
        <ListGroup className="my-2">
            <h2 className="text-center">Items</h2>
            {todoItems}
        </ListGroup>
    )
}
```

}
export default TodoList

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        todos: [],
        stuff: ''
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    this.addNewTodo = this.addNewTodo.bind(this)
}

handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
        stuff:event.target.value
    })
}

handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()

    let body = JSON.stringify({todo: {item: this.state.stuff} })
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/todos', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
             },
        body: body,
        })
        .then(response => {response.json()})
        .then(todo => {this.addNewTodo(todo)})
}

addNewTodo(todo){
this.setState({
  todos: this.state.todos.concat(todo)
    })
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-10 mx-auto mt-4">
                    <h1 className="text-center">Todo List</h1>
                    <TodoInput 
                    stuff={this.state.stuff}
                    handleChange={this.handleChange}
                    handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                    />
                    <TodoList 
                    todos={this.state.todos}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    )
}
```

}

Comment: Can you please post your `App` class's `render()` method?

Comment: @AkshitMehra alright updated

Comment: Just for confirmation, is the structure of your single `todo`, `{id: 1, title: 'Something'}`?

Comment: @AkshitMehra I used rails generate model Todos item:string done:boolean, do i need to make them all the same name?

Comment: Put a `console.log` inside your `addNewTodo` function and log all the `todo` objects that you are adding to state. Your error says one of them is undefined, so let's make sure that you're not adding any undefined objects at this point. Better yet, go ahead and log the entire 'todos' array and see what it contains.

Comment: I think Rails automatically adds an `id` column to its models. So, when you're fetching the seed data, the todos do have respective `id`s available. But when you press the submit button to add a todo, it doesn't have an `id`, until it reaches the Rails database, and Rails automatically adds that. Is it so?

Comment: @AkshitMehra yea when i go to localhost:3000/api/v1/todos.json i can see id values associated to each todo item

Answer (score 0):

when your component is renders first "todos" won't have any value, it will be undefined. try below code

> class TodoList extends React.Component {
>   render() {
>       const { todos } = this.props;
>
> ```
> if (todos) {
>   return (
>     <ListGroup className="my-2">
>       <h2 className="text-center">Items</h2>
>       {todos.map(title => (
>         <TodoItem key={title.id} title={title} />
>       ))}
>     </ListGroup>
>   );
> }
> return "";   } }
> ```
>
> export default TodoList;